# message-driven-channel-adapter stopped processing messages

Tags: spring-integration

I have noticed that after few days running this stopped consuming messages from the queue with no known reason or trace, i have to restart it to continue processing. 
Are there any known reasons behind this, also how to find out what happened in such cases and ways to fix it. 
I am using WMQ and need to maintain transaction while processing a message. Thanks You.

```
 <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter  
                            acknowledge="transacted"  
                            destination="inboundQueue"  
                            channel="inboundChannel" 
                            auto-startup="false" 
                            max-concurrent-consumers="5" 
                            transaction-manager="transactionManager"
                            recovery-interval="60000"/>
```

Also i will like to turn on debug on this consumer thread(s) to print that its trying to get a message, is there a way to do that.

**EDITED***

I see that this had deadlocked, please let me know the cause and possible resolution, thanks.

"receivingTaskExecutor-12" - Thread t@961
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.isRunning(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:348)
    - waiting to lock <66a37d72> (a java.lang.Object) owned by "mqReceivingTaskExecutor-10" t@878
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.scheduleNewInvokerIfAppropriate(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:715)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.messageReceived(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:692)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:317)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:243)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1102)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:996)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked <5a9e40d2> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

---

"receivingTaskExecutor-10" - Thread t@878
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for <35212499> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2081)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.offer(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:328)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.CallerBlocksPolicy.rejectedExecution(CallerBlocksPolicy.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:822)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.doRescheduleTask(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:682)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.rescheduleTaskIfNecessary(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:519)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1036)
    - locked <66a37d72> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked <78ff22ed> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely is some problem up-stack (hung in user code somewhere). Use `jstack <pid>` to see what the container thread is doing when you hit this condition.

Comment: Thanks Gary, since this is the beginning of the flow, reading a message from queue and than sending downstream for processing, not sure what up-stack problem you are referring to. I see this problem again today. The application is running but there are more than 500 messages in the queue, for some reason the messages don't get picked up.

Comment: I mean the thread is likely stuck in some component downstream of the adapter. jstack will tell you.

Comment: Ok, got it. I suspect it has something to do with making session transaction as it did work fine earlier. I will have to wait for next time to see jstack. is there a way i can set session timeout here to see if there is the problem.

Comment: The simple answer is to ensure your task executor has enough threads to satisfy the container concurrency settings and, you should not use a `CallerBlocksPolicy` for the container's task executor.